# How to Install pycocotools through Conda

Tags: pycocotools

- Enviroment

OS:windows 7

Python:Python 3.7.3

Conda:conda 4.8.2

Step1: download soucre code of pococtools from github with linker fellowing: https://github.com/philferriere/cocoapi

Step2: build & install pococotall package by running

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace,

python setup.py build_ext install
```

sequently.

1. ModuleNotFoundError:No modul named 'Cython'
   [image]

   **Soluttion:** pip install Cython
2. Error: command 'cl.exe' failed:No such file or directory
   [image]

   **Solution:** install Visual Studio 2019 and ensure install 'Desktop development with c++' enviroment.

After deal with all probelem,you can run the two instrustion to finish the installment.You can run

```
conda list
```

and then check pycocotools.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 15):

This worked for me:

```
pip install pycocotools-windows
```

Answer (score 9):

I just went down this list until I found one that worked:

```sh
conda install -c conda-forge pycocotools
conda install -c conda-forge/label/gcc7 pycocotools
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 pycocotools
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf202003 pycocotools
```

Annoyingly, it seems that for some setups `pycocotools` will install just fine. But then, when you want to import it, the script will freeze at the import step. In that case, just go down the list and try the next one.

The last one (and most recent) worked for me, so perhaps start there.

Comment: This still doesn't work for me. I'm using the following on a Windows 10 64-bit environment: Conda 4.8.3 and Python 3.7.7

Comment: Worked fine for me with mamba: `mamba install -c conda-forge pycocotools`

Answer (score 3):

Following the same steps as specified [here](https://www.kaggle.com/c/tgs-salt-identification-challenge/discussion/62381):

- Install Visual C++ 2015 Build Tools from [here](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691126) with default selection.
- Go to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools and run vcbuildtools_msbuild.bat
- In Anaconda, run
- `pip install git+https://github.com/philferriere/cocoapi.git#egg=pycocotools^&subdirectory=PythonAPI`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using conda & pip together, this worked for me:

```
conda install Cython
pip install pycocotools
```

Answer (score 0):

Conda seems to have issues with pycocotools installations ,official [link](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pycocotools) dosent mention windows.
You may want to look into this [solution](https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi/issues/169#issuecomment-663941980) on github for pycoco installation on windows. Worked for me.
Better to use the [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/pycocotools-windows/) for installation.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
 pip install pycocotools-windows
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will work

conda install -c conda-forge pycocotools

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).