# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pycotools'

Tags: python, anaconda

I have created an environment in Anaconda by running:

> conda create --name myenv

switched to that environment after creation and added conda-forge to the anaconda channels.
Then I ran

> conda install pycotools

Installation seem to be successful.
When I try to import pycotools in Python

> from pycotools import models

I get the error message:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pycotools'

To verify installation of pycotools, I run

> conda list pycotools

But this gives nothing back
However, when I run

> conda list

I find pycotools in the list.

How can I verify that I have pycotools installed?
And if no, how do I properly install pycotools in my conda environment?
by

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60189943/how-to-install-pycocotools-through-conda

Answer (score 1):

Try to execute `pip install pycotools`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29933047)

Comment: @FluxedScript: While I'd certainly prefer more detail, it _does_ propose an answer. It is suggesting that the OP use `pip` instead of `conda`. I'm not convinced that will make much of a difference here, but that's a reason to downvote the answer, not delete it.